# MySQL update statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying to update a specific column in a table with data from the column of another table. I tried running the below command, but I am getting a syntax error at line 3.

```
UPDATE af_application af 
SET application_price=rss.application_price 
FROM rss_applications rss 
WHERE af.application_id=rss.application_id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE af_application af, rss_applications rss 
SET application_price=rss.application_price 
WHERE af.application_id=rss.application_id
```

Comment: @David: is `application_id` covered with any index in `rss_applications` table? And how many rows are updated?

Comment: what do you mean by `index`? Are you referring to whether `application_id` is the primary key? If so `application_id` was set to be the primary key of the table. Only ~6000 records are updated.

Comment: @David: by saying `index` I mean http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html. If it is already a PK - then yuo have nothing to do anymore. (except of adding `af.application_price <> rss.application_price` to your `where` condition.

Comment: Thanks for the links on indexes.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `FROM` in an `UPDATE` statement. You'll want to use `JOIN` instead.

```
UPDATE af_application af 
JOIN rss_applications rss 
ON af.application_id=rss.application_id
SET af.application_price=rss.application_price
```

For more information, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I get a syntax error at line 3 `JOIN...`

Comment: @David - Sorry, I accidentally inverted `SET` and `JOIN`! I updated the answer. If it's slow, make sure that you have indexes on the `application_id` fields in both tables.